# cellForRowAtIndexPath Property Change Changes Multiple Cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**Disclaimer: I'm on iOS 8, so there's a chance this is a bug.**

I'm attempting to programmatically edit the backgroundColor of a cell at a particular IndexPath in a UITableView after a particular event. I use the following code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.84 blue:0 alpha:1];
```

While this works well, as soon as I scroll, I see other cell(s) with the changed background color. I *think* it has something to do with the following code in my `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method:

```
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
...
```

I suspect since all cells are generated with this identifier, somehow the properties are getting confused (though the style doesn't then apply to everything, only random cells, so that's points against this theory). Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should never change the contents of a cell outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Cells are "recycled" as they scroll out of view and back into view, and any change not made in that method will evaporate on scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the background for all cells.

```
if (/* some condition for special background color */) {
    cell.backgroundColor = ... // special background color
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor = ... // normal background color
}
```

This avoid the reuse issue. You must follow this pattern for any cell attribute you wish to set differently for certain cells.

Comment: I assume you mean in the `tableView...cellForRowAtIndexPath...` method? If so, that would require reloading the tableView every time I want to change a property on a single cell, would it not? **EDIT** I think I understand what you mean...so I should set a default background color for new cells, but also set the background color based whether the event that changed the cell color happened. I'll try this...

Comment: Yes, in `cellForRow...`. And no, it doesn't mean you need to reload the table view, ever.

Comment: @RubenMartinezJr. - You use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` to reload only part of the table.

Comment: I think this is working! I'm setting the background color on my event like I was before, but I also have this if condition in the `tableView...cellForRowAtIndexPath...`. When the rows load, they check if my event has fired for that row.  If so, adopt the background color! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way you can change the background color like that below. For example you want to change alternate row color :-

```
     - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
if (indexPath.row%2== 0) {
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
}
else {
 [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to make cell selectable and unselectable do this:

```
var selected = [Int:Int]()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCellTypeClass

    //check if the cell button is selected
    if((selected[indexPath.row]) != nil){
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }else{
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    return cell;
}

func selectCell(index: Int){
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! YourCellTypeClass

    if((selected[index]) != nil){
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        selected[index] = nil
        print("unselected: \(index)")
    }else{
        ccell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        selected[index] = index
        print("selected: \(index)")
    }


}
```